# Computations Based on Conditions

Tags: apex

Starter here... Just wanna ask about the structure of my code, especially the if-else conditions.

These are the objects:

**A__c (Parent)**

**B__c (Child)**

Is it possible to have if-else statements inside an else statement?

**Controller**

```
public class ComputeParentChild {
    ApexPages.StandardController con;
    A__c aaa {get;set;}
    List<B__c> bbb {get;set;}

    public ComputeParentChild(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        con = controller;
    } 

    public void compute(A__c aaa, List<B__c> bbb) {

        for(A__c a2 : aaa) {
            for(B__c b2 : bbb) {
                if (a2.Type__c == 'Gold'){
                    if(a2.Total_Item_Amount__c <= $30000){
                        a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + a2.Support_Service_Charge__c;      
                    }
                    else {
                        a2.Support_Service_Charge__c = 0;
                        a2.No_Support_Service_Charge__c = true;
                        a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c;     
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(a2.Total_Item_Amount__c <= $15000) 
                        a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + a2.Support_Service_Charge__c;  
                    }
                    else {

                        a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + (a2.Support_Service_Charge__c / 2);        
                    }

                }
            } 

        }

    }
}
```

**MyController** - another apex class holding the simultaneous saving of Parent and Child Objects

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public A__c aaa {get;set;}
    public List<BWrapper> blist {get;set;} 


    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        con = controller;
        this.aaa = (A__c)controller.getRecord();

        blist = new List<BWrapper>();


    }

    public PageReference save() {

        List<BWrapper> b_list = new List<BWrapper>();
        List<B__c > newBList = new List<B__c >();
        Decimal total = 0;
        for(BWrapper bloop : blist) {
            b_list.add(bloop);
        }

        A__c a_loo = new A__c();

        a_loo.Name = aaa.Name;
        a_loo.Status__c = aaa.Type__c;

        a_loo.No_Support_Service_Charge__c = aaa.No_Support_Service_Charge__c;
        a_loo.Support_Service_Charge__c = aaa.Support_Service_Charge__c;


        insert a_loo;

        if(b_list !=null && !b_list.isEmpty()) {

            for(BWrapper er : b_list) {
                B__c bTemp = new B__c ();
                bTemp.Price__c = er.b2.Price__c;
                bTemp.Item__c = er.b2.Item__c;

                bTemp.A__c = a_loo.id;
                newBList.add(bTemp);

            }
        }

        if(newBList.size() > 0) {
            insert newBList;
        }


        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + a_loo.Id);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }

    public class BWrapper {

        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public B__c b2 {get;set;}

    }



}
```

**sampleTrigger**

```
trigger sampleTrigger on B__c (After Insert, After Update, Before Insert, Before Update, Before Delete) {

     ComputeParentChild cpc = new ComputeParentChild ();

     if(Trigger.IsBefore) {

         if(Trigger.IsInsert) {

             cpc.compute(Trigger.New);
         }

         if(Trigger.IsUpdate) {
             //some code

         }

         if(Trigger.IsDelete) {

             //some code
         }
     }

     if(Trigger.IsAfter) {

         if(Trigger.IsInsert) {

             //some code
         }

         if(Trigger.IsUpdate) {

             //some code

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, That is possible I don't see any problem in that. Are you facing any problem or getting any compiler error.

Comment: The only issue that I can see is that you have `$<some amount>` in your conditions. The dollar sign isn't required. In fact, if you're running into compilation errors, I suspect this would be the culprit. Looking at your code, the inner loop over the `B__c` records is currently unnecessary.

Comment: Is `aaa` supposed to be a `List<A__c>`?

Comment: Where are you using `b2` in logic except iteration?

Comment: @Ashwani please see edited post. I already added the other apex class holding the saving and also the trigger referencing the ComputeParentChild apex class.  'b2 ' , aside from ComputeParentChild, is also used in the MyController  class, as the B__c variable inside a wrapper

Comment: Statement `op.compute(Trigger.New);`. Where is matching signature method? As in post this method is taking two parameters `compute(A__c aaa, List<B__c> bbb)`.

Comment: @Ashwani by op I mean cpc, just typo error. I edited again my post. What do you mean by "matching signature"? term not familiar to me, sorry

Comment: No. of parameters defined method are different than you are passing in `compute` method from the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

`If`/`else` statements (and loops) can be nested any number of times.  Your code has a few compliation issues though.

1. The `$` is not used to denote a number as currency - in code, you can just use a regular integer or decimal number in comparisons or assignments to currency fields.
2. I think you meant the first argument to be a `List<A__c>`, or it was not supposed to be in a `for` loop.
3. It looks like you are missing an opening brace on the third `if` statement.

   ```
   public void compute(List<A__c> aaa, List<B__c> bbb) {//Converted to a list
       for(A__c a2 : aaa) {
           for(B__c b2 : bbb) {//This seems unnecessary, since you only operate on a2
               if (a2.Type__c == 'Gold'){
                   if(a2.Total_Item_Amount__c <= 30000){
                       a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + a2.Support_Service_Charge__c;      
                   }
                   else {
                       a2.Support_Service_Charge__c = 0;
                       a2.No_Support_Service_Charge__c = true;
                       a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c;     
                   }
               }
               else {
                   if(a2.Total_Item_Amount__c <= 15000)/*You missed this opening brace*/{
                       a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + a2.Support_Service_Charge__c;  
                   }
                   else {

                        a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + (a2.Support_Service_Charge__c / 2);        
                   }

               }
           } 

       }
   }
   ```

In addition to the above, you can condense your `else` statement into one line with a ternary statement, if you want to reduce some of your code:

```
else{ //a2.Type__c != 'Gold'
    a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + 
        (a2.Support_Service_Charge__c / (a2.Total_Item_Amount__c > 15000 ? 2 : 1));
}
```

Comment: actually, this class is attached to a trigger, and there's also another apex class that handles the simultaneous saving of Parent and Child Objects

Comment: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, sampleTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert  trigger body is invalid and failed recompilation: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [ComputeParentChild].compute(List<B__c>): [].....................here's the error

Comment: I changed the method definition, so anything calling it will need to call it with a `List<A__c>` instead of `A__c`.  If it was supposed to only take a single record, change that part back and take out the first `for` loop, since you can't iterate over a non-collection object.

Comment: You're right about using List for A__c object. And I already changed it based from your suggestions. But, there's still the error, pointing both the trigger and the save method in MyController. By the way, I modified my post and already included these two, just in case you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

`b2` is no where used in logic except iteration. Nothing being changes in `bbb` list. As per the post `compute` getting Argument of `List` type only from `Trigger`.

Try replacing your method with this.

For me this translates into:

```
public void compute(List<A__c aaa>) { // Note: This is a List!

    for(A__c a2 : aaa) {

        if(a2.Total_Item_Amount__c <= $15000 || (a2.Type__c == 'Gold' && a2.Total_Item_Amount__c <= $30000))
        {
            a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + a2.Support_Service_Charge__c;
        }
        else if(a2.Type__c == 'Gold') // > $30000 Gold
        {
            a2.Support_Service_Charge__c = 0;
            a2.No_Support_Service_Charge__c = true;
            a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c;
        }
        else // Not a Gold, > $15000
        {
            a2.Overall_Amount__c = a2.Total_Item_Amount__c + (a2.Support_Service_Charge__c / 2);
        }
    }
 }
```